# Example of blob storage and retrieval in mysql for an audio file using C#

Tags: c#, mysql, blob

Can anyone give me an example of how to use `BLOB` in MySQL?

For example, how to insert value into a table if the data type is declared as `BLOB`.

This is for an audio file.

Answer (score 1):

Just an example how to get a BLOB:

```
private byte[] GetBlob(MySqlDataReader rd, string field, Int32 len)
{
    byte[] ret = new byte[len];
    if (len > 0) rd.GetBytes(rd.GetOrdinal(field), 0, ret, 0, len);
    return ret;
}
```

To insert an audio file you could use `byte[] f=File.ReadAllBytes()` and then use **f** as parameter in an insert command.

Answer (score 0):

you may want to have a look here: http://aspalliance.com/1093_Serialization_in_Database.all

also - as a side note, this site may help you as well: http://www.netmanners.com/email-etiquette/email-etiquette-101/